# What is the proper URL to get flag service?

Tags: flags, 8, services

I'm running Drupal 7 with the Services module and the [Flag Service modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_service) installed  but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to Get countall for a particular post ? Can anyone please tell me what URL I should use ?

URL to get all posts : http://webaddess/rest/events

URL to get one Post : http://webaddess/rest/node/3591

Comment: I managed to find URL but getting this error : 406 Not Acceptable : There is no flag with node

I am doing POST with this URL : http://website.com/rest/flag/countall

 Header :
             Content-Type: application/json
             x-csrf-token: token
Body :
{
"flag_name":"content_favorite",
"content_id":"3591"
}

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement this for DrupalGap/jDrupal:

https://github.com/dontmcyn/flag/blob/master/flag.js#L282

Essentially you make a `POST` to `?q=rest/flag/countall.json` and send along the following data:

```
var data = {
  flag_name: 'my_flag_name',
  entity_id: 123
}
```

You may have to `JSON.stringify(data)` before sending it. And you are right, pass along an `X-CSRF-Token` header in the `POST` call, the value of the token can be retrieved here: `?q=services/session/token`

Comment: not sure how to use JSON.stringify(data) ? If you can explain it I will really appreciate it ?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=JSON.stringify ;)

Comment: Thanks :) But I did that before asking you. Actually I am very beginner

Comment: It all depends on what "type" of JavaScript you are doing to make the call (XMLHttpRequest, jQuery.ajax, etc). But in most cases you just do `var data = JSON.stringify({ flag_name: 'my_flag_name', entity_id: 123 });`